# Custom style for custom role in Asciidoctor PDF

Tags: asciidoctor

Say I have a custom block role:

```
[.disclaimer]
No guarantees.
```

Is it possible in Asciidoctor PDF to set a custom style (e.g. background color) for this block role? I couldn't find the answer in the [Asciidoctor PDF Theming Guide](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/master/docs/theming-guide.adoc).

Comment: have you managed to find the answer?

Comment: I generate HTML from Asciidoc and then use `wkhtmltopdf` to generate PDF from that.